# Tags for question about VS source control plug-in

Tags: support, tags

Are there any Stack Overflow tags appropriate for a question about configuring a Visual Studio Source Control Plug-in?

Comment: Re *"Visual Studio"*: Do you mean *[Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen No, Visual studio Pro (or Enterprise, or Community). Specifically, for the Git Source Code Control plug-in for Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) tag for questions about VS Code.

There are other tags like [plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plugins) and [version-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-control) but you probably should not use these, since they are probably "meta tags" which describe the *context* of the question rather than what expertise would be needed to answer it. So without knowing anything more specific about your question, I'm not sure there are any other tags you ought to use. Generally it's worth adding a tag if somebody would need specific knowledge of that concept in order to write a good answer to your question.

If you are unsure which tags are appropriate for your question, you can read tags' info which usually describes what questions the tag should be used for, and you can browse the [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) list to look for more options. If still in doubt, just post the question anyway; other community members can edit your question to fix the tags if necessary.